# Hbase change data capture

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, cloudera

I have a use-case where i want to capture the data changes (Insert/Update) in Hbase tables which is getting populated via Kafka.

I have tried the following approach but it doesn't seem to work. [Hbase change data capture](https://github.com/mravi/hbase-connect-kafka)

Is there any other way i can achieve the task.

Comment: What issue are you facing? I have extended that to following : [kafka-hbase-connector](https://github.com/nishutayal/kafka-connect-hbase). You can try once and see if that helps you.

Comment: My usecase involved capturing any new rows added to select tables as well as any column update. Is it possible to achieve with above implementation. Sorry I am new to hbase didn't understand the complete code of yours

Comment: OKay so your HBase table is updated based on Kafka events? In that case it should  work.

Comment: Also, will be better, if you post the error for debugging :)